PDF not generated from Django template
I am working on a form where I need to pass the user inputs into a context which is then passed to Django template which should be converted to a PDF file. However, instead of getting a PDF attachemnt in the recipent_mail, I got an HTML email.
Here is the custom function that generate a PDF:
def generate_pdf(context, template_name):
    template = get_template(template_name)
    html = template.render(context)
    result = BytesIO()
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if pisa_status.err:
        raise Exception("PDF generation failed")
    return result.getvalue()

And here is the custom send_mail function:
def custom_send_email(
    subject,
    template_name=None,
    context=None,
    recipient_email=None,
    email_from=None,
    send_pdf=False,
    content_type="text",
    body=None,
    file_name=None,
):
    if not subject or not recipient_email or not email_from:
        raise ValueError("subject, recipient_email, email_from are required!")
    if content_type not in ["text", "html"]:
        raise ValueError("content_type must be either 'text' or 'html'!")
    if content_type == "text" and not body:
        raise ValueError("body must be provided when content_type is 'text'!")
    if content_type == "html" and not context:
        context = {}

    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key=settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        
        if content_type == "html":
            email_content = (
                render_to_string(template_name, context) if template_name else body
            )
            email = Mail(
                from_email=Email(email_from),
                subject=subject,
                to_email=Email(recipient_email),
                content=Content("text/html", email_content),
            )
        else:
            email = Mail(
                from_email=Email(email_from),
                subject=subject,
                to_email=Email(recipient_email),
                content=Content("text/plain", body),
            )
        if send_pdf == False and file_name:
            raise ValueError("Cannot set file_name when send_pdf is False!")

        if send_pdf:
            if not file_name:
                file_name = "attachment.pdf"
            pdf_content = generate_pdf(context, template_name)
            encoded_pdf = base64.b64encode(pdf_content).decode()
            
            attachment = Attachment()
            attachment.file_content = encoded_pdf
            attachment.file_type = "application/pdf"
            attachment.file_name = file_name
            attachment.disposition = "attachment"
            email.attachment = attachment

        response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=email.get())
        logger.debug(f"Email response: {response.status_code}")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Email sending error: {e}")
        raise e

